# FireFox keyboard active button

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Having a UI that is meant to be keyboard friendly. It has various controls in the for of buttons etc.

Problem is that when one click a button by keyboard, the button does not get the `:active` status. I have a strong style to show it gets `:focus` - but the active status is only triggered when one use mouse and click with main button.

This makes things very user-unfriendly. It looks as if the button is not activated. The page has frozen or the like. One risk users clicking multiple times as they expect a visual feedback.

---

From what I read at MDN it looks as this is a *feature* in the CSS3 specification:

> **Note:** On systems with multi-button mice, CSS3 specifies that the :active pseudo-class must only apply to the primary button; on right-handed mice, this is typically the leftmost button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

---

As this is a JavaScript based UI, I have tried to solve this by JS on the `click` event:

Add, and remove a `.activated` class.

This does not work as the page is not re-rendered. To fix this without using a `setTimeout()` I have tried things like these:

https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/#article-header-id-0

```
element.classList.add('activated');
void element.offsetWidth;                // Trigger reflow
element.classList.remove('activated');
```

No effect.

I have tried to add class, remove element, insert a new *with* the class, and remove the class. No effect.

Used `dataset-active=1` and CSS by that. No effect. Same issue as with adding and removing class.

And some other things.

I have also tried to use `setTimeout()`, but this is somewhat buggy. Especially if one use Enter key (to trigger multiple clicks.)

In the end I also tried to listen for keydown, keyup etc. setting statuses if it was enter, space or mouse click etc. But that quickly got very messy.

---

Is there a neat trick for this that I am missing? A solution that is not overly complex.

---

#### Sample code

```css
button:focus {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
button:active {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="counter.value = ++counter.value;">Button</button>
<input id="counter" value="0">
```

Comment: One thing that I see missing is the basic code in order for people to duplicate the issue [mcve].

Comment: added sample code

Comment: How do you listen for the keyboards events?

Comment: @flappix: `elem.addEventListener('key…', some_fun)` – but it is a no-go from what I see, as one have so many cases to check it quickly becomes too complex for such a simple issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about that: Adding a data-attribute containing the related keycode to the button. While pressing the key down an `active` class is assigned and `click()` and `focus()` are triggert. When the key is released the `active` class will be unassigned.

```js
 
document.onkeydown = function (evt)
{
    let btn = document.querySelector ('[data-key=' + CSS.escape (evt.keyCode) + ']');
    if (btn)
    {
        btn.classList.add ('active');
        btn.click();
        btn.focus();
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function (evt)
{
    let btn = document.querySelector ('[data-key=' + CSS.escape (evt.keyCode) + ']');
    if (btn)
    {
        btn.classList.remove ('active');
    }
}
```

```css
    button:focus {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

button.active, button:active {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button data-key="32" onclick="console.log(1);">Button 1 [space]</button>
<button data-key="16" onclick="console.log(2);">Button 2 [shift]</button>
<button data-key="13" onclick="console.log(3);">Button 3 [enter]</button>
```

Alternatively you can take a look at [accesskey attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_accesskey.asp).

Comment: Thank you for the effort. Problem here, (If I'm not missing your logic), is that this would activate _all_ buttons with data-key set. I ended up using `document.addEventListener('keydown' / 'keyup', ff_fix_active, true);` and toggle active status if target is a button. Really do not like doing a global trap for each key press like this, and might look at it more later. But works for now.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If you press space if will just trigger button 1, if you press return it will just trigger button3. If you want a new button just add an element with a data-key attribute.

Comment: Yes. But I have more then 40 buttons that all should have enter and space trigger active status.

Comment: So 40 buttons should be triggered simultaneously by pressing enter?